# How do I write chefspec code for seven_zip_archive resource?

Tags: chef-infra, chefspec

I have used a resource seven_zip_archive to unzip files. I need to write chefspec code for this resource. I have not found any solution yet.

I tried something like:-

```
it ('updates 7zip') do
            expect(chef_run).to add_windows_path("xyz_driver_install_unpack").with(path:"C:\\Program Files\\XYZ Driver")
      end
```

Recipe:-

```
seven_zip_archive "#{cookbook_name}_#{recipe_name}_unpack" do
  not_if { ::Dir.exist?(install_directory) }
  path install_directory
  source media_file
end
```

I get error like:-

> Failure/Error: expect(chef_run).to
>   add_windows_path("xyz_driver_install_unpack").with(path:"C:\Program
>   Files\XYZ Driver")

```
   expected `"windows_path[xyz_driver_install_unpack]"` with action :add to be in Chef run.
```

Comment: Do you intend to install the 7zip program or extract a 7zip archive?  (ex a file ending in .7z or .zip) - perhaps the docs can help? https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/seven_zip#readme

Note that the `seven_zip` cookbook is used to install the 7zip program and the `seven_zip_archive` resource can extract a 7zip compatible file. `seven_zip_archive` shouldn't modify the windows path.

Comment: I wanted to use the seven_zip_archive resource to unpack/unzip the installed files in a directory. With regard to that I wanted to test this resource seven_zip_archive through chef spec.